# Can i create a gcode that self destructs after one instance of printing?

Tags: g-code, 3d-printing

Can i create a gcode that self destructs after one instance of printing? For example I send the gcode created to a printer at a remote area to print but I want them to only print it once. Can i add a self destruct code so that it deletes after running once?

Comment: What you need is called [Non-disclosure agreement (NDA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on which firmware your printer is using.  "Gcode" is interpreted differently on different printers.

Marlin is a very popular firmware and runs on nearly every entry-level printer, such as Creality printers (CR-10, Ender 3, etc), Wanhao/MP MakerSelect, etc.
You can find a full documentation of every available gcode command here:  https://marlinfw.org/meta/gcode/

With that said, not all GCode commands are implemented by every printer.  Some printers trim out GCODE that isn't commonly used to keep the firmware file small, thus allowing them to make the "brains" of the printer with a cheaper microcontroller.

There IS a delete from SD card option, the code is "M30" and is documented here: https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M030.html
Your printer may not support this though, so you'll have to test it out yourself.
The usage is:

```
M30 /path/to/file.gco
```

You'll have to know the path to the file, and this relies on your path not changing, so it may not be very practical.  This command is generally something used by someone issuing commands to a printer manager, not something you should be sticking at the end of a gcode file to self-destruct.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, you cannot.  There is no GCODE command for self-destruct of the file (or command stream) and the GCODE commands can be processed by any number of recieving applications and firmwares.  Some work on files, others work on command streams, and some can use GCODE in either a stream or a file.  So there's no way to force the receiving app/firmware to delete the file or stream.